# Using Recursion to compare letters contained in a string?

Tags: java, recursion

After taking in two words, utilizing recursion to determine if the letters of the first word are contained IN ANY ORDER in the second word.

We can only utilize the .charAt string method and .contains is also not allowed.

I was thinking starting with the first character of the first word and seeing if it was equal to the charAt the length of the second word -1, then returning a substring of length -1 but this isn't working correctly.

```
public static boolean containedWordsCheck(String firstWord,String secondWord) {
//Recursion
        if (firstWord.charAt(0) == secondWord.charAt(secondWord.length()-1))
            return containedWordsCheck(firstWord.substring(1, firstWord.length()-1),secondWord.substring(1, secondWord.length() - 1));
        //If it reaches this far it means the letters in the first string aren't contained in the second string
        return false;
```

Comment: If the first word is `"apple"` then do there have to be two p's in the second word?

Comment: If the characters can be **in any order** in the second word, your logic fails because you're comparing the first character in the first word to the _last_ character in the second word, but not to any other character in the second word.  "In any order" means that that character could be anywhere in the second word, right?  There are other errors in your logic, but you'll need to come up with a better plan anyway.

Comment: Have you studied loops already?

Comment: If string buffers or substrings were allowed, maybe I could see a point in recursion. If not, it's hard to see, but of course recursion can be used if your professor insists. :-)

Comment: If the first letter of the first word is the same as the last letter of the second word, you are chopping off a letter at *both* ends of both words? This can't be right.

Comment: containedWordsCheck("abbbb","aaaba") must be true or false?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. It is using helper recursive function and only charAt() as you proposed. Complexity will be O(n^2). If you do pre sort, it will be a lot easier as you can see in other answer.

```
public boolean containedWordsCheck(String firstWord,String secondWord) {
    if (firstWord.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (containChar(secondWord, firstWord.charAt(0))) {
        return true && containedWordsCheck(firstWord.substring(1, firstWord.length()), secondWord);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean containChar(String word, char ch) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (word.charAt(0) == ch) {
        return true || containChar(word.substring(1, word.length()), ch);
    } else {
        return containChar(word.substring(1, word.length()), ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: On one hand this is spoon-feeding and probably not the best way to help the asker. On the other hand the idea is exactly right.

Comment: @Ole V.V. You are right, I will be more careful next time ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FunLetters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String a = "apple";
        String b = "pplea";

        char[] aArr = a.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(aArr);
        char[] bArr = b.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(bArr);
        boolean answer = checkForSameString(aArr, bArr, 0);
        System.out.println(answer);

    }


    private static boolean checkForSameString(char[] a, char[] b, int i) {

        if (i == a.length || i == b.length)
            return true;
        if (a[i] == b[i])
            return checkForSameString(a, b, i + 1);
        return false;
    }
```